# Why do Windows 10 updates never restart automatically and finish updates?

Tags: windows, updates

I have access to several computers running all major versions of Windows: Windows Server, Windows Pro and Windows Home. They are all configured to update at a certain time and restart automatically, however none of them do. What happens is that they happily start updating and when they should reboot either one of two things happen:

- They say they are going to reboot but they just shutdown. Obviously when I power them back up they still need to finish updating.
- They do reboot but they wait until I log on before they finish updating at which point I am *greeted* by a "Getting things ready", "Finishing updates" or some other message of that sort.

Now, for my computers at home, even though infuriating, I suppose I can live with it, but for the computers at work which are running either Pro or Server editions, we have applications on them that need to be online and can't afford having them offline while someone comes in to work after a weekend to log on so that they finish updating.

How can I preferably force Windows to actually finish updating and completely boot up and start running our applications after an update, or disable them completely?

Comment: Server operating systems shouldn't restart automatically - all the server versions of windows we have resource manual control of their updates / restarts !?

Comment: I thought as much. I assume the IT guys should have configured those, but what about the Pro ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its only recently that Windows 10 pro are not rebooting after update.  Until now, I had assumed that something else had gone wrong with Windows just on my PC.

You cant naturally disable updates but you can Pause them

1. Go to Windows Update
2. Click on Advanced Options
3. Pause updates (at the bottom) for max 35 days

But if you are willing to apply a registry tweak then you can stop updates. I would recommend [Winaero Tweaker](https://winaerotweaker.com/).  **I am not associated with it and it is free.**

1. In the tree on the left, find **Behaviour**
2. Click on **Disable Windows Update**
3. Tick the box

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I don't want to disable updates. I want to make sure they actually go through without any user interaction.

Comment: "or disable them completely?"  Did that mean something else.

Comment: No, but I don't think I am allowed to stop security updates. I also don't know if I can tweak the registry. I'll have to check, and I'll get back to you.

Comment: You could enable the updates when you know thst thete are security updates available.  The only way to prevent updates fouling up uptime. Sometimes it installs the updates with a reatart pending. but the system stops working. In my last company. the windows manager was pushing updates when he was ready with them, to the client's machines.